# OMXPlayer script exiting with "have a nice day"

Tags: script, omxplayer

I am trying to open up an rtsp stream on system boot. I have enabled auto login, which works well.

I just cant get the script to work, even in isolation

```
#!/bin/sh -x
omxplayer -n -1 rtsp://<username>:<password>@<ip address:port>/stream
```

The actual command inside the script works fine from the command line but just exits when running using the script. I just see "Have a nice day" and then nothing.

Any help is greatfully received.

Comment: The -g option for omxplayer should create a log file. Can you incorporate that into your script, rerun and check the log for anything useful?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Any idea where the logs go by default?

Comment: *edit* - should have looked a bit more closely.. They are in the same directory as the script.

I can see it opening the stream but then just Exited with Thread, then thread stopped

Comment: Thank you so much.. your post pointed me in the right direction.. I'd actually got the port wrong. *slapsownface*